# NoReverseMatch Exception for links in Django ListView

Tags: python, django

I've created an app that automatically generates a `slug` based on the `title` of a posting, using [django-autoslug](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug/1.7.2).

I've successfully displayed each of the posts in a `ListView`, but am having trouble linking to the `DetailView`. Thoughts?

I'm receiving the following error:

`Reverse for '/scholarships/test-scholarship-1/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

**Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from autoslug import AutoSlugField


class Scholarship(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('single_scholarship', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**Views**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Scholarship


class ScholarshipDirectoryView(ListView):
    model = Scholarship
    template_name = 'scholarship-directory.html'


class SingleScholarshipView(DetailView):
    model = Scholarship
    template_name = 'single-scholarship.html'
```

**URLs**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import ScholarshipDirectoryView, SingleScholarshipView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ScholarshipDirectoryView.as_view(), name='scholarship_directory'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/$', SingleScholarshipView.as_view(), name='single_scholarship'),
)
```

**Relevant Template**

```
{% for scholarship in scholarship_list %}
<p><a href="{% url scholarship.get_absolute_url %}">Read more &rarr;</a></p>
```

I have to be missing something stupidly obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the actual full URL from `scholarship.get_absolute_url` to the `{% url %}` tag. You should use one or the other, not both: either `{{ scholarship.get_absolute_url }}` *or* `{% url 'single_scholarship' scholarship.slug %}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
{{ scholarship.get_absolute_url }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<a href="{{scholarship.get_absolute_url}}">Read more &rarr;</a>
```